# CKEditor change in ajax URL ?t=timestam to ?open&t=timestamp

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, lotus

I use the CKEDITOR on my HTML page, but I can not connect it properly, my WEB server does not understand such requests and I need to change them.

My WEB server does not support requests like ?t=timestamp.
How can I change this, for example, to have ?Open&t=timestamp.
I have the following requests:

```
GET http://mysite.ru/webadmin/ckeditor/config.js?t=H4PG 400 (Bad Request)
GET http://mysite.ru/webadmin/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=H4PG (Bad Request)
GET http://mysite.ru/webadmin/ckeditor/lang/ru.js?t=H4PG 400 (Bad Request)
```

Should be so

```
GET http://mysite.ru/webadmin/ckeditor/config.js?open&t=H4PG
GET http://mysite.ru/webadmin/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?open&t=H4PG
GET http://mysite.ru/webadmin/ckeditor/lang/ru.js?open&t=H4PG
```

How to set my suffix for all connected plug-ins?

It seems to me that there is some parameter that will allow you to insert your HTTP command after the question.

Example,

```
CKEDITOR.config.<param>="open&"
```

or callback function

```
function(request){
     request+="open&";
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: Can this help? http://dontpanic82.blogspot.dk/2011/01/ckeditor-using-external-plugins-from.html

Comment: I corrected the question, perhaps it will be more understandable.


I need to insert in the Get request the insert "open &" when setting up the CKEditor

Comment: That's exactly what CKEDITOR_GETURL handles - therefore the link to the blog post above. I am using it with CKEditor to allow plugins to work with Domino

Comment: No you need a better web server or to at least tell use what web server your using or better yet post this on https://serverfault.com/ as it's relating to a bad server configuration no server should prevent `.js?t=` that is standard use of a query string any web server that does not do it is not a standardised web server so don't expect it to work with standardised browsers or Standardised Langs such as HTML / CSS / Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Tried it like this

```
   function CKEDITOR_GETURL( resource ){
    var base="/webadmin/ckeditor/"; 
    var r=resource;
    if(!/^\//.test(r))r=base+r;
    return r;
}
```

But some of the resources are not properly processed, a bad idea